# Julia: nested loops for pairwise distances is really slow

Tags: julia

I have some code which loads a csv file of 2000 2D coordinates, then a function called `collision_count` counts the number of pairs of coordinates that are closer than a distance `d` of each other:

```
using BenchmarkTools
using CSV
using LinearAlgebra

function load_csv()::Array{Float64,2}
    df = CSV.read("pos.csv", header=0)
    return Matrix(df)'
end

function collision_count(pos::Array{Float64,2}, d::Float64)::Int64
    count::Int64 = 0
    N::Int64 = size(pos, 2)
    for i in 1:N
        for j in (i+1):N
            @views dist = norm(pos[:,i] - pos[:,j])
            count += dist < d
        end
    end
    return count
end
```

Here are the results:

```
pos = load_csv()

@benchmark collision_count($pos, 2.0)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  366.03 MiB
  allocs estimate:  5997000
  --------------
  minimum time:     152.070 ms (18.80% GC)
  median time:      158.915 ms (20.60% GC)
  mean time:        158.751 ms (20.61% GC)
  maximum time:     181.726 ms (21.98% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          32
  evals/sample:     1
```

This is about 30x slower than this Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance

pos = np.loadtxt('pos.csv',delimiter=',')

def collision_count(pos, d):
    pdist = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(pos)
    return np.count_nonzero(pdist < d)

%timeit collision_count(pos, 2)

5.41 ms ± 63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Any way to make it faster? And what's up with all the allocations?

Comment: julia <1.5 needs to allocate a small structure for views. 1.5 fixes this (and a bunch of other types of allocations)

Comment: Have you tried using [Distances](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl)? From memory that package has some impressive optimizations...

Comment: Come to think of it, for Euclidean distances the computations can be done using BLAS, which is almost certainly what the Python package is doing. So to match that speed you'll either need to structure your Julia code so it uses BLAS functions, or else just use the Distances package which AFAIK will do this for you.

Comment: Come to think of it even further, this is one of those problems that it doesn't really matter what language you implement it in. If your code is using BLAS under the hood then it will be fast, and if it isn't then it will not be fast. You may still observe some differences depending on which BLAS implementation the language is calling. For example, AFAIK the Intel MKL library will often beat openBLAS, which was the default library that Julia used last time I checked.

Comment: Turns out that idiomatic Julia is nevertheless able to get a factor of 5 faster than python, Sometimes, vectorized code is just slower.

Comment: You should be using function `pairwise` from Distances.jl
https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl#computing-pairwise-distances

Comment: I'm seeing pairwise be slower than my version. Any ideas why?

Comment: BLAS is only faster for large arrays. Unless each column is _long_, BLAS will probably be pretty slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest I can get trivially is the follows

```
using Distances
using StaticArrays
using LinearAlgebra

pos = [@SVector rand(2) for _ in 1:2000]
function collision_count(pos::Vector{<:AbstractVector}, d)
    count = 0
    @inbounds for i in axes(pos,2)
        for j in (i+1):lastindex(pos,2)
            dist = sqeuclidean(pos[i], pos[j])
            count += dist < d*d
        end
    end
    return count
end
```

There are a variety of changes here, some stylistic, some structural. Starting with style, you may note that I don't type anything more restrictively than I need to. This has no performance benefit, since Julia is smart enough to infer types for your code.

The biggest structural change is switching from using a matrix to a vector of `StaticVectors`. The reason for this change is that since points are your scalar type, it makes more sense to have a vector of elements where each element is a point. The next change I made is to use a squared norm, since `sqrt` operations are expensive. The results speak for themselves:

```
@benchmark collision_count($pos, .1)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.182 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.214 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.218 ms (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     2.160 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4101
  evals/sample:     1
```

Note that there are `n log(n)` algorithms that may be faster, but this should be pretty close to optimal for a naive implementation.

Comment: You are being too restrictive on the `d` argument. There's no reason it can't be a different type than the array eltype, e.g. the array can hold floats, and `d` could be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on specific knowledge about the dimensionality of the points:

(**Edit:** I updated the function to make it more robust with respect to indexing. Some `AbstractArray`s have indices that do not start at 1, so now I use `axes` and `lastindex` instead of `size`.)

```
function collision_count2(pos::AbstractMatrix, d)
    count = 0
    @inbounds for i in axes(pos, 2)
        for j in (i+1):lastindex(pos, 2)
            dist2 = sum(abs2(pos[k, i] - pos[k, j]) for k in axes(pos, 1))
            count += dist2 < d^2
        end
    end
    return count
end
```

Benchmarks:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime collision_count(pos, 0.7) setup=(pos=rand(2, 2000));
  533.055 ms (13991005 allocations: 488.01 MiB)

julia> @btime collision_count2(pos, 0.7) setup=(pos=rand(2, 2000));
  4.700 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The speed is actually close to the `SVector` solution. On the upcoming Julia version 1.5, the difference compared to the OP's code should be much smaller, since `view`s become more efficient.

BTW: drop the type annotations, like these

```
count::Int64 = 0
N::Int64 = size(pos, 2)
```

it's just adding visual noise.